# DontDestroyOnLoad through scenes for Audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't change the volume of the music more than 1 time. The volume control is on a "Settings" scene, so when I move to this scene I  can change the volume of the game sound, but when i go out of the scene and come back I can't. I guess that happens cause of my bad DontDestroyOnLoad usage.
Once I change the volume the DontDestroyOnLoad comes in so the volume doesn't change once you go out of the scene, but when you come back to Settings to change it back it doesn't work cause of the DontDestroyOnLoad.
How can I solve this so I can change it wherever I want?

```
public class soundCont : MonoBehaviour {


    private static float musicVolume = 1f;

    private static float SetVolumeFX = 1f;
    private void Start()
    {
        musicVolume = Musicafondo.instance.musicSource.volume;
    }

    void Update ()
    {    
        MusicBack.instance.musicSource.volume = musicVolume;
        MusicBack.instance.efxSource.volume = SetVolumeFX;
        MusicBack.instance.efxSourceEnemy.volume = SetVolumeFX;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);           
    }    

    public void SetVolume(float vol)
    {
        musicVolume = vol;
    }

    public void SetVolumeFx(float vol2)
    {
        SetVolumeFX = vol2;
    }
}
```

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); should be set on Start, and probably MusicBack.instance.efxSource.volume and MusicBack.instance.efxSourceEnemy.volume require a different setup. Could you please show those methods?

Comment: @JackMariani `public AudioSource efxSource;
    public AudioSource efxSourceEnemy;
    public AudioSource musicSource;
    public static MusicBack instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != null)
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
    } 

    public void PlaySingle(AudioClip clip)
    {
        efxSource.clip = clip;
        efxSource.Play();
    }

    public void PlaySingleEnemy(AudioClip clip)
    {
        efxSourceEnemy.clip = clip;
        efxSourceEnemy.Play();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Both the instance you're using for the volumes are don't destroy on load, so you do not need to store the last values of the volume on a field.

This code solve your issue:

```
private void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    MusicBack.instance.musicSource.volume = 1f;
    MusicBack.instance.efxSource.volume   = MusicBack.instance.efxSourceEnemy.volume = 1f;
}

public void SetVolume(float vol) { MusicBack.instance.musicSource.volume = 1f; }

public void SetVolumeFx(float vol2)
{
    MusicBack.instance.efxSource.volume = MusicBack.instance.efxSourceEnemy.volume = vol2;
}
```

`SetVolume` will change the music volume and `SetVolumeFx` will change the volume of the sound effects.

Make also sure `SetVolume` and `SetVolumeFx`  are called properly.